# Uploaded CSV file parsing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my rails app, how can I access data from an already uploaded csv file? I have used paperclip to upload the file successfully, but struggling to find any tutorials or references on how to parse the data. I have seen http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel but this seems to be helpful for uploading into database columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [API for the CSV class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) 
Something along the lines of:

```
CSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv") do |row|
  # use row here...
end
```

Comment: Thanks Yule. I'm struggling to find the location of the file as it's via paperclip and puts it under the system folder in a long folder structure that different for each post I have.

Comment: You could use attachment.path?